# Sliding jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery dropdown (more like drop right!) menu. What I need is that when the mouse is over the home button (for example), the other buttons slides out, and the content box slides in.

I want the black box (content) to slide in from the end of the button. Right, the box is sliding in from the left edge of the screen...but I don't want that box to be under the "home" button, I want it to be next to it.

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TvNcD/

It's buggy right now...
But I think it's something fairly simple to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it works for you although I think there should be a better way to do this using CSS3...http://jsfiddle.net/TvNcD/18/

Comment: Well, it's very buggy. Is there any way to make the black box "float" left? So that the other buttons won't shift down when the box slides in? Also, that when the cursor is in the black box, it won't slides back out?

Comment: <http://jsfiddle.net/TvNcD/65/> It still has couple of bugs but I it can be solved using this plugin..<http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html> I haven't tried it yet but you can give it a shot...

Comment: Thanks for your time. It helped me a bit, now I need more help on something else. Thanks again